# Add a space between two variables inputs

Tags: string, csv, dictionary

#I get the following error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

#when using my print code:

print (("Value if purchased on "+str (date))("= $")+ str(my_dictionary[str(date)]))

#i was able to print out prior but I couldn't get a space between the date and the value of my_dictionary.

#printed
Value if purchased on 2021-02-164.17

#when i used the code as following

print (("Value if purchased on "+str (date))+ str(my_dictionary[str(date)]))

#please advise. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python's f-string feature. This allows you to join literals and expressions easily.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
value_dict = {
              str(today - timedelta(days=1)): 100, 
              str(today): 200, 
              str(today + timedelta(1)): 300
             } 
        
print(value_dict)
print(f"Value if purchased on {str(today)}: {value_dict[str(today)]}")
```

Output:

{'2021-03-17': 100, '2021-03-18': 200, '2021-03-19': 300}

Value if purchased on 2021-03-18: 200

Comment: thanks how do I rate you. someone got mad at me because i didn't rate them. don't know how. i'm a newbie. thanks!

Comment: Press the checkmark near my name to mark the question as answered: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work